# React Native running android with different version

Tags: android, react-native

When I run 'react-native run-android' it always checks 'android-23' version and I don't have any AVD with android-23.
Instead I only have android-21.
How can I specify android version of android-21?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to update your SDK. To do so, you need to open Android Studio. Then, go to Preferences -> Appearance & behaviour -> System Settings -> Android SDK. You will see a few tabs:

1. SDK Platforms
   Check 'Show Package Details' at the right bottom corner and check the following items  under Android 6.0 (Marshmallow): 
   Google APIs, 
   Android SDK Platform 23, 
   Sources for Android SDK
2. SDK Tools
   Check 'Show Package Details' at the right bottom corner and check the following items:

Android SDK Build Tools 23.*
Android Auto API Simulators
Intel x86 Emulator Accelator (HAXM installer)

Click on Apply button, wait for everything being installed, and then try to run your project again.

Comment: In that case I can't test the app on the device with old android version, right? I want to test the app on the device with same android version

Comment: Open Tools -> Android -> AVD Manager,  click on "Create Virtual Device" button at the left bottom corner, choose a device, click Next, chose an API level within one of the Recommended ones or check other tabs with alternative API Levels. After that, run the device and run `react-native run-android`. Does it work for you?

Comment: I haven't installed android-23 so I can't test.  I can only create AVD device with android-21

Comment: Once you install Android 23, you will be able to chose what API level to use for a specific device

Comment: That is my point, i don't want to install Android 21, because I have to test it on old devices

Comment: My point is that it doesn't matter how many APIs you have installed. You will be able to test devices on any of them

Comment: Really? Thanks I am trying to install android 23 now